# How do I use Elasticsearch NEST to return results using match search?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I am trying to write a simple console app using C# and NEST to learn more about Elasticsearch.

I can run the following query in Sense (Kibana)

```
GET /companies/company/_search
{
    "query": {
          "match": {
              "dbaName": "STEAK"
         }
     }
}
```

and I will get back the following result:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.15342641,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "companies",
        "_type": "company",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.15342641,
        "_source": {
          "dbaName": "We do steak",
          "primaryLicenseStatus": "T",
          "primaryLicenseDescription": "Restuarant",
          "lastActivityDate": "2016-06-06T08:25:23.4136549-04:00"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, when I try to do this query using NEST, I get no results:

```
var response = client.Search<Company>(s => s
    .Index(theIndex)
    .Query(q =>
        q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.DbaName).Query("steak"))
    )
);
```

**UPDATE - I figured it out!**
So I feel like I should take this post down since the question has no relevance to the solution.

Spoiler: My query in NEST is fine.

I had created a console app that would start by deleting the index, re-creating it, insert the Company and then search for it.
The server was not keeping up with my console app and only when I stopped deleting/recreating the index was I able to get the search to work.  (facepalm)
If any feel that I should simply delete this thread, let me know in the comments below and I will remove it, but someone may find it helpful.

Comment: What does the serialized form of the NEST query look like? What analyzer (if any) is set on the `dbaName` field?

Comment: Thanks Russ for your response.  I apologize, I am a bit of a newb to Elasticsearch and am not 100% sure how to get answers for your questions.  I have not specified an analyzer, so I am assuming the default is being used.  I've poked around how to find out and am not coming up with a solid article to explain.

Comment: No worries :) You can log requests/responses with something like Fiddler (`targeting `ipv4.fiddler:9200` instead of `localhost:9200`), or you can use `OnRequestCompleted` as per - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38215585/1831.   Documents that are indexed are not immediately available in search, you need to wait for the refresh interval (default is 1 second) before they will appear in search documents. You can manually refresh which is useful for testing but should try to avoid calling it frequently in production.

Answer (score 0):

The first step in your debugging process should be to view the request that is being made to ES and compare it with what you're expecting.

Here is a great extension method to get the raw json that was sent to ES:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Debugging method to get the json that was sent to ES
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetRequestString(this IResponse response)
    {
        var request = response.RequestInformation.Request;
        if (request != null)
        {
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(request);
        }
        return response.RequestInformation.RequestUrl;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Two things: First: `response.RequestInformation` is throwing an error.  I'm using NEST 2.3.3 if that matters.  Second: my `var request = response.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes;` is returning null.  Thoughts?

Comment: Okay I had to change a setting to get the Request Body back.  The body is this: `{"query":{"match":{"dbaName":{"query":"steak"}}}}`  Which when I run in Sense, it works.  Thoughts?